# How do I save the view clipping plane settings?

Tags: 3d-view

In this menu, I always set the clip start value to be 0.01m, because the default of 0.1m is not small enough for my use cases where I am frequently close to objects.

[image: View Menu]

However, this setting resets back to 0.1m every time I restart Blender. Is there a way to save it so that it automatically uses 0.01m when I open Blender?

Comment: Have you tried _`File > Defaults > Save Start Up File`_ after setting the setting?

Comment: This works! However, note that you need to do this when you have nothing open, as it saved the model I was currently working on into the start up file... so I just deleted everything and re-saved. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.